# Microsoft Graph V1 Getting Member using list lookup field

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have a lookup field in a SharePoint list that offers the (lookup) id for a user that exists within Microsoft. The `id` is something similar to `100`. I want to be able to use that `id` through Microsoft Graph to retrieve the associated member.

I have no idea how SharePoint uses that id to find the user.

```
"fields": {
   "User1LookupId": "138"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id used in lookup fields is from the SharePoint user list. The SharePoint user list is not in Microsoft Graph, rather you need to use the SharePoint REST API to get the user information:

`https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/web/GetUserById(lookupId)`

This call should return the UPN, which you can use to get the Microsoft Graph User (if needed).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531432(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#user-resource

Comment: Yes.  Take a look at [the Community Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-contrib/blob/master/docs/ROADMAP.md#sharepoint-siteusers) which leverages the auth provider in the Graph SDK.

(Not sure GetUserById is implemented yet, but should be straightforward to add...)